# How to get a RAW16 from CX3

Tags: usb

This is my data flow for my system:

[image]

Because i can not found a demo to config a raw16, and i did not found the enum type "enum CyU3PMipicsiDataFormat_t " which not contain a RAW16type,

so i did't known how to transfer my raw16 data to the host.

I try to use the yuv422 configuration to transfer my raw data to the host, and i really received data from the CX3 by e-cam, but the image is wrong for the e-cam use the yuv2 formating to resolve the raw data. And now I think i can use the matlab to grap a frame and deal with it. But when i use the matlab getting a snashot and i found the data is a

type like this: 1280*800*3(full frame size:1280x800). Is it the matlab regard as a yuv data? and how can i config the cx3 to support raw16  or how to deal with the data i grap from the cx3 with the yuv format transfer.

Is there any other developer meet the requirement like me?